# Selecting Disjoint Range of Data with Variable Last Row Using GetRangeList Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet `sheetUnitsDB` with a bunch of data. I want to select the data from specific columns and paste it onto another sheet `sheetRentRoll`. I could do this by selecting each *entire* column specified and feeding it into `getRangeList`, but for efficiency, I'd like to only include the rows that have data. There are two ways I see of doing this using `getRangeList`:

**Option 1: Use `getRangeList` with r1c1 Notation**

The developer page claims `getRangeList` can take a1notation **or r1c1 notation**. Does anyone know how to feed r1c1 notation into `getRangeList`? In my example below, the `LastUnitRow` is 10 so I am attempting to select the range [C5:C10]:

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
var sheetRentRoll = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Rent Roll');
var sheetUnitsDB = activeSheet.getSheetByName('UnitsDB');

var LastUnitRow = sheetUnitsDB.getLastRow(); //Last row of RentRoll DB with data, 10 in this example

var testrange = sheetUnitsDB.getRangeList([5,3,LastUnitRow-4,1]); //should select range C5:C10 but yields error
Logger.log(testrange)
```

This returns the error: "Exception: Range not found". I know my notation is wrong but don't know how to fix it.

**Option 2: Convert r1c1 to a1 and Use getRangeList with a1 Notation**

If it is somehow erroneous that `getRangeList` can be used with r1c1 notation, alternatively I have a code in the example below that takes the r1c1 notation above for the range [C5:C10] and returns "C5:C10". I convert this to a string which returns "['C5:C10'] and attempt to pass this to `getRangeList` which also returns an error:

```
var app = SpreadsheetApp; 
var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //Get current active spreadsheet
var sheetRentRoll = activeSheet.getSheetByName('Rent Roll');
var sheetUnitsDB = activeSheet.getSheetByName('UnitsDB');

var LastUnitRow = sheetUnitsDB.getLastRow(); //Last row of RentRoll DB with data, 10 in this example

var rangeR1 = sheetRentRoll.getRange(5,3,LastUnitRow-4,1); //selects range C5:C10
var rangeA1 = rangeR1.getA1Notation(); //returns "C5:C10" (without quotation marks)
rangeA1 = "['" + rangeA1 + "']";

Logger.log(rangeA1); //returns ['C5:C10']
var testrange = sheetUnitsDB.getRangeList(rangeA1); //should select range C5:C10 but yields error
Logger.log(testrange)
```

which gives the error: "Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRangeList."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the documentation search on getRangeList() look at tutorial

Comment: Hi, the link you provided is for getRange, not getRangeList. I need getRangeList since I will be selecting a discontinuous range of data. I've searched the documentation for getRangeList with r1c1 and cannot find it anywhere.